# How do you calculate a "time range" in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I've got a column that looks like the following... There can be any number of duplicate entries.  I want to be able to have a cell somewhere else that will calculate the "date range" of the column.  I.e., "1 week, 3 months, 3 years".  Anyone have any idea how to do this?

```
25-Mar
25-Mar

26-Mar
26-Mar

26-Mar
26-Mar
27-Mar

27-Mar
27-Mar
28-Mar

28-Mar
28-Mar
31-Mar

31-Mar
31-Mar
1-Apr
```

Comment: You do, of course, need the year for accuracy: you might be in a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in A1:A21:

```
MAX(A1:A21) - MIN(A1:A21)
```

Should return the **number of days** between the latest and earliest date.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks, Christopher!

Comment: @JordanFine glad I can help.  Can you select this as the answer so that it appears to be closed.